# Searching an exact phrase with Facebook's Ad Library API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm attempting to do a keyword-based search of political ads via [Facebook's Ad Library API](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/api/?source=archive-landing-page) and am struggling with how to format my search_term entry in a way that searches for an exact phrase, rather than any ads containing the above keywords. I've tried quotes within the quotes but that hasn't changed the results in any way.

My searches generally are for candidate names and for those with common names it means I'm casting far too wide a net. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Not sure that’s possible. The description of the search_terms parameter states they treat a space between words like a logical AND (that not enough to find candidates by name though?), and there doesn’t seem to be much else. `bylines` appears to require the complete byline to be specified, and you probably won’t know that exactly in each case I’m guessing.

Comment: @CBroe I appreciate the response. While a space requires both terms, it doesn't require them consecutively. I'd be getting these 2000+ word rambling posts that some weirdo chose to promote and just so happened to included both "John" and "James" in them, paragraphs apart.
I'm instead refining the data locally to only include observations with the full name and accepting the call limits.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is from a while ago, but posting in case it helps someone else. There is now a parameter named "search_type" in the Ads Archive API (documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/ads_archive/)) which can be set to "KEYWORD_EXACT_PHRASE". This will search for exact matches of the term(s) in in "search_terms".